# Cassandra Load status does not update (nodetool status)

Tags: cassandra

Using the `nodetool status` I can read out the `Load` of each node. Adding or removing data from the table should have direct impact on that value. However, the value remains the same, no matter how many times the `nodetool status` command is executed.

Cassandra [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsStatus.html) states that the `Load` value takes 90 seconds to update. Even allowing several minutes between running the command, the result is always wrong. The only way I was able to make this value update, was to restart the node.

I don't believe it is relevant, but I should add that I am using [docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/) to create the cluster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsStatus.html) that you linked, under `Load` it also says

> Because all SSTable data files are included, any data that is not
>   cleaned up, such as TTL-expired cell or tombstoned data is counted.

It's important to note that when Cassandra [deletes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html) data, the data is marked with a tombstone and doesn't actually get removed until compaction. Thus, the load doesn't decrease immediately. You can [force a major compaction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCompact.html) with `nodetool compact`.

You can also try flushing memtable if data is being added. Apache [notes](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable) that

> Cassandra writes are first written to the CommitLog, and then to a
>   per-ColumnFamily structure called a Memtable. When a Memtable is full,
>   it is written to disk as an SSTable.

So you either need to add more data until the memtable is full, or you can run a `nodetool flush` (documented [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsFlush.html)) to force it.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any reference for flushing the memtable?